# Iris classification ipython using numy operations

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am following the book `Building Machine Learning Systems with Python`. After loading the dataset from `scipy` I need to extract index of all features belonging to setosa. But I am unable to extract. Probably because I am not using a `numpy` array. can someone please help me in extracting index numbers? Code below

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

import numpy as np
# We load the data with load_iris from sklearn

data = load_iris()

features = data['data']

feature_names = data['feature_names']

target = data['target']
for t,marker,c in zip(xrange(3),">ox","rgb"):

# We plot each class on its own to get different colored markers
plt.scatter(features[target == t,0], features[target == t,1],
            marker=marker, c=c)

plength = features[:, 2]

# use numpy operations to get setosa features

is_setosa = (labels == 'setosa')

# This is the important step:

max_setosa = plength[is_setosa].max()

min_non_setosa = plength[~is_setosa].min()

print('Maximum of setosa: {0}.'.format(max_setosa))

print('Minimum of others: {0}.'.format(min_non_setosa))
```

Answer (score 0):

Define labels before the problem line.

```
target_names = data['target_names']
labels = target_names[target]
```

Now these lines will work fine:

```
is_setosa = (labels == 'setosa')
setosa_petal_length = plength[is_setosa].
```

*Extra.
Data Bunch from sklearn ( data = load_iris() ) consists of target array with numbers 0-2 which are related to features and means sort of the flower. Using that you can extract all features belonged to setosa (where target equals 0) like:*

```
petal_length = features[:, 2]
setosa_petal_length = petal_length[target == 0]
```

Confront this with data['target_names'] and you will get two lines on the top which are solution to your question. By the way all arrays from the data are ndarrays from NumPy.